In Java, draw geometric shapes such as seen in Jamaica flag 
I need to figure out how to draw the Jamaica  flag in Java on visual studio code.

I cannot figure out how to draw the flag. All I know is that I must used this header:
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class JamaicaComponent extends JComponent {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 

I have tried this code, but it doesn't work as expected
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class JamaicaComponent extends JComponent 
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        //jamaica flat
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(10, 10, 180, 60);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect(10, 70, 180, 60);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(10, 130, 180, 60);
    }
    
}

What the code renders:


Since we're specifically interested in the rendered image, it may be appropriate in this case to include a screenshot of your current (buggy) behavior. Note that the flag of interest has diagonal lines / non-rectangular polygons (hint), you may need something other than #fillRect to accomplish this task.

What part of your code didn't work as expected? What would you expect different? In your code you specified 3 rectangles of equal width, height, and x-coordinate, only differing in what y-coordinate you used. Make sure to check the Documentation for Graphics.

Hint: a rectangle (as drawn by Graphics2D) is one with horizontal and vertical edges, hardly appropriate to draw that flag-- you need to draw triangles - maybe fill() or fillPolygon() - check the documentation of Graphics2D for details

( I would use fillRect() to fill the whole area with yellow [as background], and then draw the triangles )

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/TOC.html

java.awt.Color and java.awt.Graphics

If you would like to use the exact colors: Color green = new Color(0x009B3A);  Color black = Color.BLACK;  Color gold = new Color(0xFED100);

The first thing in paintComponent is supposed to be a call to super.paintComponent(g); It probably doesn't matter if you are painting the entire area of the component, but it is a good habit to get into. Also, you have a lot of hardcoded numbers. You should probably be requesting the width and height of the component and going off of that. As others have said, you need more than rectangles.

Fill with green. Draw two black triangles. Then two yellow lines of appropriate thickness.
public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)graphics;
    
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    
    // Fill with green
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    
    // 2 black triangles
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillPolygon(new int[] { 0, width / 2, 0 }, new int[] { 0, height / 2, height }, 3);
    g.fillPolygon(new int[] { width, width / 2, width }, new int[] { 0, height / 2, height }, 3);

    // Note: you could draw the 2 triangles as a single sideways hourglass polygon:
    //g.fillPolygon(new int[] { 0, width, width, 0 }, new int[] { 0, height, 0, height }, 4);
    
    // 2 yellow lines
    int lineWidth = height / 9;  // Just a guess. Try different values.
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(lineWidth));
    g.draw(new Line2D.Float(0, 0, width, height));
    g.draw(new Line2D.Float(width, 0, 0, height));
}




Rectangle-only solution.
Just draw the X and Y axes in yellow, and color the four quadrants of the plane alternatingly in black and green. With appropriate isometric projection, that is:
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class JamaicaComponent extends JComponent 
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        int w = 800;
        int h = 400;
        Color green = new Color(0x009B3A);
        Color black = Color.BLACK;
        Color gold = new Color(0xFED100);
        for (int r = 0; r < h; r++) {
          for (int c = 0; c < w; c++) {
            double rx = c / (double) w - 0.5;
            double ry = r / (double) h - 0.5;
            double x = (rx - ry) / sqrt(2);
            double y = (rx + ry) / sqrt(2);
            double d = min(abs(x), abs(y));
            double stripeWidth = sqrt(17) / 24 / sqrt(5);
            g.setColor(
              d < stripeWidth ? gold : (x * y) < 0 ? green : black 
            );
            g.fillRect(c, r, 1, 1);
          }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Jamaica Flag");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JamaicaComponent());
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}


Certainly a good way to memorize flags.

Wow, that's... a lot of rectangles. You could just draw two yellow rectangles by applying an appropriate affine transform to the coordinate system...

@DavidConrad Sure. But I found it more fun to render a pseudo-3D view of a yellow crossroads that turns out to look just like the Jamaican flag. It's not like we were attempting to achieve anything useful here...

Sadistic challenge: make it rotate!
